# SQL Regex Pattern, How to match only a specific variable between two characters? (see Sample Output)

Tags: regex, oracle

I have this inputs:

```
John/Bean/4000-M100
John/4000-M100
John/4000
```

How can I get just the `4000` but note that the `4000` there will be change from time to time it can be `3000` or `2000` how can I treat that using regex pattern?

Here's my output so far, it statisfies John/400-M100 and John/4000 but the double slash doesnt suffice the match requirements in the regex I have:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.demand,'/(.*)-|/(.*)',1,1),'-|/','')
```

Comment: Which SQL variety are you using?

Comment: Oracle SQL 12c @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to get the results you want:

```
select regexp_replace(data, '^.*/(\d{4})[^/]*$', '\1')
from test
```

The regex looks for a set of 4 digits following a `/` and then not followed by another `/` before the end of the line and replaces the entire content of the string with those 4 digits.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ce2cb479c6cb9fb3c02661c1606cddd)

Comment: pretty much sure right now the code is working especially on Nick, just had to minor tweaks and it work! :) Thank you

Comment: Hi @Nick! how about just a hunch if ever we have more than 4 digits like 5 digits or 6 digits? Sample below: SCP_FCSTPLAN_DFCann_SCJ_APP_YES_o7120/14161-M_02

Comment: @遊星不動 you can just change the `{4}` to match appropriately e.g. `{5}` or if you could have 4 or 5 or 6 you can make it `{4,6}`

Answer (score 0):

The following will match any multiple of 1000 less than 10000 when its preceded by a slash:

```
\/[1-9]0{3}
```

To match any four-digit number preceded by a slash, not followed by another digit, such as 4031 in—

> Sal_AS_180763852/4200009751_S5_154552/4031

—try:

```
\/\d{3}(?:(?:\d[^\d])|(?:\d$))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Am34WO/1

Comment: how about this one?
how do you treat this @sean to match only 4031?
Sal_AS_180763852/4200009751_S5_154552/4031

Comment: it returns null on sql query:

Comment: SELECT
 REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.demand,'\/(\d{3}(?:(?:\d[^\d])|(?:\d$)))',1,1),'-|/','') as test

Comment: pretty much sure right now the code is working especially on Nick, just had to minor tweaks and it work! :) Thank you

Comment: Hi @Nick! how about just a hunch if ever we have more than 4 digits like 5 digits or 6 digits? Sample below:
SCP_FCSTPLAN_DFCann_SCJ_APP_YES_o7120/14161-M_02

Answer (score 0):

This would also work, unless you need any digit followed by three zeros. See it in action here, for as long as it lives, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23656/5

```
create table test_table 
( data varchar2(200))
insert into test_table values('John/Bean/4000-M100')
insert into test_table values('John/4000-M100')
insert into test_table values('John/4000')

select a.*,
       replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.data,'/\d{4}'), '/', '')
from   test_table a
```

Comment: It seems okay but there are some instance like:
Sal_AS_180763852/4200009751_S5_154552/4023
its getting the  4 digits for the first slash "/4200" instead of "/4023"

Comment: pretty much sure right now the code is working especially on Nick, just had to minor tweaks and it work! :) Thank you